# How do I change the background color of a text box based on the value in it in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

So I have 2 textboxes A and B which by a commandbutton click gets populated automatically.

How do I change the background color of the textboxes when the values in them change ( If a user changes the values in them manually) ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also is there any way I can make integer appear with one decimal point . For example, 50 should be 50.0

Comment: For the first question look at the textbox's `Change` event and look at the various properties of the control.  For the second, look at the `Format` command...

Comment: Dave- I used format command but it gives out 2 decimal points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vinay, You would do that like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
   TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

You'll want to put that in the `TextBox1` object (double clicking it will get you there). The color change will be triggered when the value of the text box is changed. If I've understudy your question correctly, this should solve your problem. If not, please let me know.

**SUPPLEMENT : A breakdown of the code**

`Private Sub TextBox1_Change()` is an event handler. The code inside will run whenever a particular event occurs. In this case, whenever the text inside the TextBox1 changes.
`TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)`

`TextBox1` is an object, in this case it is your first texbox which is by default named "TextBox1", but we could use any other object in your form, "TextBox2", "Button1" etc...

`.BackColor` is a property of `TextBox1` (its Back Color). We could set the `BackColor` property to any valid color, but here I went with red.

`RGB` stands for Red Green Blue. In this case we set the back of the `TextBox` to a color equil to 255 (All Red), 0 (with no Green), and 0 (No Blue).

**SUPPLEMENT 2**
So, based on your last comment, you would be looking to do something like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If TextBox1.Text = "5" Then
        TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "6" Or TextBox1.Text = "4" Or TextBox1.Text = "5.6" Then
        TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jim , If I do what you said the color initially is red and it doesnt change

Comment: Right, you would have to change it back using the same mechanism. If you tell me how you want the color to toggle I can walk you through it.

Comment: OK.. the initial color must be white when the default value is present (say 5 ) and when a user manually changes the value ( to 6 or 4 or 5.6 etc), then the color must change to red

Comment: Okay, give the supplements to my answer a look over and see if that helps. I'll keep checking in, so feel free to post followups.

Comment: @Vinay billa, Glad to here it! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

When you click on the CommandButton:

```
TextBox1.Backcolor = 'something (example: &H000000FF&)
```

If the content of the TextBox is changed, use:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
   'Change the color
   'Just an example:

   If TextBox1.Text = "Hello" then
      TextBox1.Backcolor = &H0000C000&
   Else 
      TextBox1.Backcolor = &H000000FF&
   End If

End Sub
```

The .0 thing:

```
Label1.Caption = Ineteger & ".0"
```

You really don't need to round or anything, because you have Integers.